# Update content inside a view in SwiftUI after user logges in

Tags: firebase, authentication, swiftui

I am working on authorization logic for a mobile app in SwiftUI.
I have implemented firebase authentication to handle loginn register and log out.
My problem is that when I test the login section I can see it updates the user status initially set to false `@Published var signedin = false`, but the content inside remains the same unless I manually refresh the view, then the content is updated `Text("signed in")`

in my `ModelViewApp` model I have set the `signedin` state to false

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseAuth
import SwiftUI

class ModelViewApp: ObservableObject {
    @Published var signedin = false
    
    let auth = Auth.auth()
    
   
    
    var isSignedin: Bool {
        return auth.currentUser != nil
    }
    
    
    func signIn(email: String, password: String) {
        auth.signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) {
             [weak self] result, error in
            guard result != nil, error != nil else {
                return
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.signedin = true
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    func signUp(email: String, password: String){
        auth.createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) {
             [weak self]  result, error in
            guard result != nil, error != nil else {
                return
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.signedin = true
            }
        }
    }
    
    func signOut() {
        try? auth.signOut()
            self.signedin = false
        
    }
    
}
```

I have this `ContentView` I have called Login(viewModel: viewModel) to ensure that I am not creating a new instance

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var viewModel =  ModelViewApp()
  
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            if !viewModel.signedin {
                Login(viewModel: viewModel)
                }
            else {
                VStack{
                    Text("signed in")
                    UButton(text: "mena", color: .blue){
                        viewModel.signOut()
                        
                    }
                }
                
            }
            
        }
        .onAppear {
            viewModel.signedin = viewModel.isSignedin
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
               ContentView()
    }
}
```

And this is my Login view

```
struct Login: View {
    
    @State var email = ""
    @State var password = ""
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ModelViewApp
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            TopSection(tittle: "The kill", subtitle: "new", Background: .blue)
                
                Form {
                    
                    TextField("wrap your heard", text: $email) .disableAutocorrection(true).autocapitalization(.none)
                    SecureField("wrap your heard", text: $password)
                        .disableAutocorrection(true).autocapitalization(.none)
                    
                    
                    UButton(text: "mena", color: .blue){
                         guard !email.isEmpty, !password.isEmpty else {
                            return
                        }
                        viewModel.signIn(email: email, password: password)
                    } 
                }
            
            VStack{
                Text("Have an account yet?")
                NavigationLink("Create an account", destination: SignIn_())
            }
           
            }
       
        }
  
}

      
    
struct Login_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
            return Login(viewModel: ModelViewApp())
    }
}
```

Still I have to manually refresh the content inside `ContentView` to see it changed when I do I see `Text("signed in") UButton(text: "mena", color: .blue){ viewModel.signOut()}` I hit the button to test the logic works and it takes me back to login in, so I can see that one works.
Am I creating a new instance of it when ever I login that I am not aware of or what should I do to have it reload `ContentView` once the user logs in?